# unit test for angular responseError interceptor with 'notify' promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have angular responseError interceptor, which implements logic of resending request to server if a previous attempt was unsuccessful. Moreover the interceptor returns 'notify' promise to keep in touch about current status.

```
return {
        responseError: function(response) {

            var retries = angular.isDefined(response.config.headers['X-RETRIES']) ? response.config.headers['X-RETRIES'] : 0;
            response.config.headers['X-RETRIES'] = retries + 1;

            if (response.config.headers['X-RETRIES'] <= MAX_XHR_ATTEMPTS) {
                var $http = $injector.get('$http'),
                    defer = $q.defer();

                $timeout(function() {
                    defer.notify('trying');
                    defer.resolve($http(response.config));
                }, 1000);

                return defer.promise;

            } else {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }

        }
    };
}
```

It's example but it works properly, for unit tests I use tdd, mocha, chai, sinon. I used similar code: (the interceptor is injected in above code)

```
test('test', inject(function($http, ) {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/test').respond(500);
        var promise = $http.get('/test');

        $httpBackend.flush();
        promise.then(
            function(data) {
                dump('success', data);
            },
            function(data) {
                dump('error', data);
            },
            function(data) {
                dump('notify', data);
            }
        );
    }));
```

But the promise doesn't return any state. if I tried to change interceptor to return 'reject' promise once as an error is occurred (without timeout and additional pull request) in this case everything works as expected. How to make test for the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't flush the $timeout - try the following:

```
   test('test', inject(function($http, $timeout) {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/test').respond(500);
        var promise = $http.get('/test');

        $httpBackend.flush();
        promise.then(
            function(data) {
                dump('success', data);
            },
            function(data) {
                dump('error', data);
            },
            function(data) {
                dump('notify', data);
            }
        );
        // Timeout after we've attached notify listener.
        $timeout.flush(1001);

    }));
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, it runs http requests in $timeout block, but I'm unable to get notify promise yet :(

Comment: Oh, probably because I told you to do the $timeout BEFORE you added the then statement. Try my edit above, moving the $timeout after. That gives you a chance to attach the notify callback. You would still have error callbacks because the promise was rejected, but notify wouldn't work. See my edit.

Comment: I solve the issue, thanks Peter! there should be used $rootScope.$digest() to send notify promise, and one more I found a good article about testing $timeout http://rudickulous.com/post/75310347493/spying-on-angulars-timeout-service